# Efficiently sampling a symmetric posterior with MCMC

Tags: sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, symmetry

I am using MCMC (via [emcee](https://github.com/dfm/emcee/)) to sample a posterior distribution $p(\vec\theta|Y)$ where $\vec\theta = (\theta_1, \theta_2, \ldots)$ are parameters for a physical model of the process generating an experimental dataset $Y$.

Due to the symmetry of the model, I know that swapping parameters $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ has no effect on the posterior probability. In other words, the posterior is even with respect to $\theta_{1,2} = \theta_1 - \theta_2$.

This means that the posterior typically has two modes, symmetrical of one another.

1. It seems like a waste of resource to sample both of them.
2. The walkers tend to split into two groups (one for each mode) and waste a lot of proposals in the region that separates the two modes (around $\theta_{1,2} = 0$)
3. The two modes are typically not sampled equally because a few more walkers would lend into either of them, failing to transition between equally important modes.

**How could I tune my usage of [emcee](https://github.com/dfm/emcee/) to perform this sampling more efficiently?**

The ideas I had so far were:

1. Combine the statistics of the modes. This is the most straightforward way, though it does not address problem (2). For each sample used for analysis, I could create a duplicate obtained by swapping its values for $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$. This guarantees a symmetric distribution (addressing (3)) and doubles the samples available for each mode (addressing (1)).
2. Enforce a prior imposing $\theta_{1,2} > 0$. This would forces the walkers to sample only one mode at a time, but I am concerned that it would lead to a large number of rejections if the mode is located near $\theta_{1, 2} = 0$.
3. Enforce a mirror-like boundary condition at $\theta_{1,2} = 0$. If a proposal lands in the $\theta_{1,2} < 0$ region, move it to the symmetric point in the $\theta_{1, 2} > 0$ region before evaluating the likelihood.

My main concern with solution (1) is that it does not address problem (2). For the other two solutions, I am unsure whether these would violate detailed balance and alter the mode's statistics.

I am especially interested in canonical solutions to this problem, if any exists.